# Asual jQuery Address is buggy in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-address

This is my second project using jQuery Address, and I think there is something weird with Firefox, or at least I can figure out that it has a different behavior in Firefox and Webkit.

When deep linking, jQuery Address should fire a change event and execute the piece of JavaScript related to this state.

For /foo/bar deep link, if I write down the event object to the console, in Google Chrome, I have two events fired :

**jQuery.Event #1**

```
path: "/"
pathNames: Array[0]
queryString: ""
timeStamp: 1335431580471
type: "change"
value: "/"
```

**jQuery.Event #2**

```
path: "/foo/bar"
pathNames: Array[2]
queryString: ""
timeStamp: 1335431580471
type: "change"
value: "/foo/bar"
```

But in Firefox, I have only one event fired, that doesn't take in account the current URI :

**jQuery.Event #1**

```
path: "/"
pathNames: Array[0]
queryString: ""
timeStamp: 1335431580471
type: "change"
value: "/"
```

So obviously in Firefox the lightbox that I want to open for the /foo/bar URI is never going to open :-(

Here is my code for jQuery address :

```
$.address.crawlable(1).state('/').change(function(event) {
    var page = event.path;
    if (page == '/foo/bar'){
        openLightbox($('#create-popup-template').html());
        create_main();
    }
});
```

For now I am using a simple workaround to make it work in Firefox, just adding a init function to force a second change event in Firefox :

```
$.address.init(function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla)
         $.address.value(window.location.pathname);
 });
```

But it's been the second time I have to do this and it doesn't feel right.. am I missing something ?

I also already tried to mess up with internal and external changes callbacks, with no chance..

Thanks for helping,

Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

I use Asual jQuery Adress plugin 1.6 that you can find here : [enter link description here](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/blob/master/src/jquery.address.js) and not on Asual website.

In this version, they have remove crawable feature (but it can be crawled by Google normaly). Additionnaly, you can compress it with http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

So it's maybe a bug of 1.5 versions